# Save Image Using .net Chart

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to save image from chart graphic. 
I'm using following line.

```
chart.SaveImage("D:\\mypic.png", System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartImageFormat.Png);
```

but I have a problem:

[image]

Here is my code.

```
protected void btnBar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string degerler = txtDeger.Text;
    ArrayList array = new ArrayList();

    if (Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text) > Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text))
    {
        Label3.Text = "TopNCount sayısı büyük olamaz...";
    }
    else
    {
        Label3.Text = "";

        for (int i = 1; i < Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text) + 1; i++)
        {
            array.Add(Convert.ToInt32(degerler.Split(',')[i - 1]));
        }

        chart.ChartType = myChart.ChartTypes.Bar;
        chart.TopNCount = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text);
        chart.DataSource = array;
        chart.DataBind();
        chart.SaveImage("D:\\mypic.png", System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartImageFormat.Png);
        this.Controls.Add(chart);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone else had that problem:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/MSWinWebChart/thread/6ca0a897-4ffe-4c67-851e-6002ee4af19d

It seems that the chart control wasn't able to locate the background used for the chart.

If that's the problem, maybe you could report the incorrect exception message on the Microsoft Connect website.

Answer (score 1):

my guess is that you can't save the chart as image because nothing has been rendered.
try to hook to the `Init`/ `Load` / `DataBound` events and try to save it from there.

**EDIT**

try the following:

```
chart.DataBound += (sender, args) => ((Chart)sender).SaveImage("D:\\mypic.png", System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartImageFormat.Png);
```

or

```
chart.Load += (sender, args) => ((Chart)sender).SaveImage("D:\\mypic.png", System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: hi sorry i cant understand what you are talking about. can you give me more information. and chart is diplay in aspx file but not save.