# How to save a Chart control picture to a file?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts, mschart

Having a chart displayed with a `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart` control in a .Net 4.0 WinForms application, can I save its render into a picture file?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

How about the [`Chart.SaveImage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456181.aspx) method?

Comment: Thanks. I haven't ever been using the Chart control before and have somehow missed the method while searching.

Answer (score 25):

You can use the code below by passing proper ChartImageFormat.*:

```
this.chart1.SaveImage("C:\\mycode\\mychart.png", ChartImageFormat.Png);
```

Also look this SO if you met any problem:
[Save Image Using .net Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304406/save-image-using-net-chart)
and 
[Saving higher resolution charts without messing up the appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641436/saving-higher-resolution-charts-without-messing-up-the-appearance)